# Image upload with React using Multer

Tags: reactjs, mysql-workbench, multer

I have watched like 20 videos of how to upload an image with React and still have no success even though i have tried multiple solutions.
I am using Node.js for the Backend and Mysql as a database.
I'd really appreciate some help as i've been stuck here for the last 3 days now :/

This is my Backend where Multer is set. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3YW6.png
This is my Frontend where React is. [2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgKm0.png

Also my Project is (in case if it's easier that way) - https://github.com/dimadeloseros1/Project7-Groupomania

Comment: Let me know what was error you get on the console.

Comment: @sedhalsoni On this particular solution I'm not sure, i can't check it out now as i am not at home. Yesterday I've spent 3 hours (no kidding) with a full stack developer and he couldn't see what was there issue. However, he made a simple Create react app from the scratch, set up a server and managed to Upload a picture with no problems.